# Silverlight 4 : Restrict checking of checkbox to box only

Tags: silverlight-4.0, checkbox

I wanted to know if its possible to disallow checking/unchecking of checkbox on clicking checkbox label and only allow checking/uncecking of the box on the box only.

PS: I want to pull it off without using an additional label for the checkbox i.e I wish to disable check/uncheck of checkbox on the checbox label

Answer (score 0):

checking the template ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078%28VS.95%29.aspx)), can't see clearly how to do that. Additionally it does not have any NamedPart. For me the easiest way is that you suggested... or create your own checkbox.